# higher direct image: proof of the proper case.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi.

Let $f:X→S$ be a proper, open, surjective morphism of complex reduced spaces with constant fiber dimension n (or universally open morphism with n-fibers between locally noetherian excellent without embedded component schemes on field of characteristic 0). Let $G$ be a coherent sheaf on X.

**Claim:** $R^{n}f_*G=0$ if and only if $Supp(G)\cap X_{s}$ is nowhere dense in the fiber $X_{s}$.

**Outline of the proof:**

1) If $Supp(G)\cap X_{s}$ is nowhere dense in the fiber $X_{s}$ and then 
 $dim(Supp(G)\cap X_{s})<n$, it is not hard to see that $R^{n}f_∗G=0$.

For this, we use the fact that $Supp(G)\cap X_{s}$ is a compact subspace of dimension $\leq n-1$ and then admit a fundamental system of $n-1$-complete neighboorhoods (Demailly result on top degre cohomology...) each of them satisfies, in particular, $H^{n}(V, G)=0$; it suffices to write the definition of the germ $R^{n}f_∗G(s)$ as an inductive limit.

2) Suppose now $R^{n}f_∗G=0$. Then we have, by duality, $\pi_*\mathcal{H}om(G, \omega^{n}_{X/S}=0$. The openness and generic smoothness)  of $\pi$ imply that $\mathcal{H}om(G, \omega^{n}_{X/S})=0$. Therefore, we can use local $S$-embedding or local $S$ parametrization:
$\begin{array}{ccc} X & \overset{\sigma}{\to} & Z \\
& \underset{\pi}{\searrow} & \downarrow q \\
& & S \end{array}$ 
where $Z$ is an $n+p$-dimensional $S$-smooth complex space, or
$\begin{array}{ccc} X & \overset{f}{\to} & Y \\
& \underset{\pi}{\searrow} & \downarrow q \\
& & S \end{array}$
where $f$ is finite, open and surjective over  $Y:=S\times U$ of relative dimension $n$.

Then the isomorphism
$$f_{*}{\cal H}om(G,\omega^{n}_{X/S})\simeq{\cal H}om(f_{*}G, {\cal O}_{Y})$$
$$\sigma_{*}{\cal H}om(G,\omega^{n}_{X/S})\simeq {\cal E}xt^{p}(\sigma_{*}G, \Omega^{n+p}_{Z/S})$$
proves the claim.
We see that the problem reduce to the case of the projection 
$q:S\times U\rightarrow S$, where $U$ is either a Stein in ${\Bbb C}^{n+p}$ or in $ {\Bbb C}^{n}$,  and coherent  sheaf $ G$ on $S\times U$ satisfiying one of this conditions:
$$ {\cal H}om( G, {\cal O}_{S\times U})=0,\,\,{\rm or }\,\,{\cal E}xt^{p}( G, {\cal O}_{S\times U})=0$$ `
We deduce what we want thanks to this:

> > Let $k$ be a noetherian local ring with residual field $\mathfrak{k}$, $R$ be a $k$-algebra formally smooth over $k$, $N$ be the Krull dimension of the regular local ring
> >     $R{\otimes_{k}}\mathfrak{k}$. Let $q$ be an integer and $M$ an  $R$-module of finite type. Then
> >     $${\rm dim}_{(R{\otimes_{k}}\mathfrak{k})} M\otimes_{k}\mathfrak{k}\leq q\,\Longleftrightarrow {\rm E}xt_{R}^{j}(M, R)= 0 \quad \text{for} \quad j<N-q$$

Comment: Sorry. I dont understand anything!!!! 

Comment: Check you TeX code, you left some dollar signs out. In case, the "only if" part is wrong: take $S$ to be a point, $X = \mathbb P^1$, and $G = \mathcal O_X$. And what is the question?

Comment: I fixed your LaTeX code, but I still don't see a question.

Comment: The question was (see the "Higher direct image..")

If $f:X\rightarrow S$ is a proper, open and surjective  morphism of reduced complex spaces countable at infinity and $G$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then

$R^{n}f_{*}G=0$ if and only if $Supp(G)\cap X_{s}$ is nowhere dense in the fiber $X_{s}$.

Comment: But this is not true, consider the map from projective space (of
poistive dimension) over a field $k$ to the spectrum of the field and
the tautological sheaf $\mathcal O(1)$ on projective space. In the
other direction it is OK.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you.

I'm confused. It is true that, for any coherent sheaf $G$ on $X$, $Supp(R^{n}f_{*}G)=\{s\in S: Dim(f^{-1}(s))\geq n\}$ ?

And if i assume,in the question,  $Supp(G)$ nowhere dense in $X$ can i hope to have the " only if " part?


Thank you.

Comment: I see now the only thing that is wrong  in the proof of the "only if":
 
I say that $f_{*}{\cal H}om(G, \omega^{n}_{X/S})=0$ imply that 
${\cal H}om(G, \omega^{n}_{X/S})=0$. It's globally true on $X$ but not locally. In general, it is false unless $f$ is finite and surjective; the openess has nothing to do...

Thanks to Laurent, Angelo and Torsten...
